# copy array without specified element java

Tags: java, arrays, copy, element

i'm trying copy an array without a specified element. Let's say I have the following arrays:

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int[] array2 = new int[array.length-1];
```

what I want is to copy array to array2 without the element containing the int "6" so it will contain 
"{1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9}"

I only want to use for loops and this is what I have so far but it doesnt work

```
int[] array= { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int[] array2= new int[array.length - 1];
    int remove = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] != remove) {
            array2[i] = array[i];
        } else {
            array2[i] = array[i + 1];
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array2[i]);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What are `tab` and `tab2`? And "but it doesnt work" is not a good replacement for an error message.

Comment: my bad, tab is array and tab2 is array2

Comment: What exactly doesnt work? do you get an error? another result? just plain nothing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int j = 0;
int count = 0; //Set this variable to the number of times the 'remove' item appears in the list
int[] array2 = new int[array.length - count];
int remove = 6;
for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
{
   if(array[i] != remove)
       array2[j++] = array[i];
}
```

Comment: thanks but the last element of array2 is not copied, there a 0 instead of a 9

Comment: @BobJ I guess you forgot to change `int count = 0;` to `int count = 1;`?

Comment: no ive put array.length2 instead of array.length . thanks it works

Comment: You may want to use the count since there may be duplicate values in the array which will result in the array having a series of 0's at the end.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do it using Java 8's streams and lambda expressions:

```
int[] array= { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int[] array2 = Arrays.stream( array ).filter( value -> value != 6 ).toArray();
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( array2 ) );
// Outputs: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayUtils.remove(array, 6)` from *apache.commons.lang* might also be suitable